# Problema com assinatura digital SHA-256

Tags: xml, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital, api

Estou gerando um xml e assinando com o SHA-256, porem ao validar a assinatura logo em seguida o java diz que ela não é válida

xml gerado e assinado:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <EnviarLoteEventos xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_0">
        <loteEventos>
            <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_0">
                <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">
                    <ideEmpregador>
                        <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                        <nrInsc>00060824000157</nrInsc>
                    </ideEmpregador>
                    <ideTransmissor>
                        <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                        <nrInsc>00060824000157</nrInsc>
                    </ideTransmissor>
                    <eventos>
                        <evento Id="ID1000608240001572017071915400600002">
                            <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_02_02">
                                <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1000608240001572017071915400600001">
                                    <ideEvento>
                                        <tpAmb>3</tpAmb>
                                        <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                                        <verProc>11.27.062.05</verProc>
                                    </ideEvento>
                                    <ideEmpregador>
                                        <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                                        <nrInsc>00060824</nrInsc>
                                    </ideEmpregador>
                                    <infoEmpregador>
                                        <inclusao>
                                            <idePeriodo>
                                                <iniValid>2010-01</iniValid>
                                            </idePeriodo>
                                            <infoCadastro>
                                                <nmRazao>CONSISANET SISTEMAS DE INFORMACAO LTDA - EPP</nmRazao>
                                                <classTrib>02</classTrib>
                                                <natJurid>2313</natJurid>
                                                <indCoop>0</indCoop>
                                                <indConstr>0</indConstr>
                                                <indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha>
                                                <indOptRegEletron>1</indOptRegEletron>
                                                <multTabRubricas>N</multTabRubricas>
                                                <indEntEd>S</indEntEd>
                                                <indEtt>N</indEtt>
                                                <contato>
                                                    <nmCtt>SOCIO TESTE</nmCtt>
                                                    <cpfCtt>03202055925</cpfCtt>
                                                    <foneFixo>04699786912</foneFixo>
                                                </contato>
                                                <softwareHouse>
                                                    <cnpjSoftHouse>00060824000157</cnpjSoftHouse>
                                                    <nmRazao>CONSISA INFORMÁTICA LTDA</nmRazao>
                                                    <nmCont>MARCIO RODRIGO DE BORTOLI</nmCont>
                                                    <telefone>04635201300</telefone>
                                                </softwareHouse>
                                                <infoComplementares>
                                                    <situacaoPJ>
                                                        <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                                                    </situacaoPJ>
                                                </infoComplementares>
                                            </infoCadastro>
                                        </inclusao>
                                    </infoEmpregador>
                                </evtInfoEmpregador>
                                <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                                    <SignedInfo>
                                        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                                        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                                        <Reference URI="#ID1000608240001572017071915400600001">
                                            <Transforms>
                                                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                                            </Transforms>
                                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                            <DigestValue>Sm0qPUX+89hnOGkQP7hsxTNUIfAryCdYBWYXM1+OmJs=</DigestValue>
                                        </Reference>
                                    </SignedInfo>
                                    <SignatureValue>a70ld/0B4VX+FiPWaXYYNjJmGHZtEV7YxjOwLeqSjcWmo45mUySGv2oyXQFEU9ahKSizPkfQoYqpERG4r/Z2qChEkpHDJkGwRCGycPd5ZdxJDht/0dip6KkGzqb/iYpdeRXq1ljlnelfMTcOvaLxaFh1PQ4hP28jFu3TxE/xEWuWA4kvIzFURcQdeuPfv/99P4lZKTX/vZAiPGePLa2QkqnqMbLrdI5Ze5D9/igt/hsWTo3OXxO3AAUAwKMwjYSaWp3Rs/i3IVKmHIk2oIxXIQGDPBCl8VJKMRUlvBXEkFT82YFy0vlSnD+REYlJyfk/ECBayt6delMLHHVRyD4Ecw==</SignatureValue>
                                    <KeyInfo>
                                        <X509Data>
                                            <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                                        </X509Data>
                                    </KeyInfo>
                                </Signature>
                            </eSocial>
                        </evento>
                    </eventos>
                </envioLoteEventos>
            </eSocial>
        </loteEventos>
    </EnviarLoteEventos>
</soap:Body>
```

código do método de assinatura utilizado

```
public static String assinarSHA256(String xml, String tagRoot, String tagId, String tagAssinar,
        CertificadoBean certificadoBean, boolean lote) throws Throwable {

    Document doc = XMLW3CUtil.stringToDocument(xml);
    NodeList elements = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagAssinar);
    int quantidade = elements.getLength();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
            Element el = (Element) elements.item(i);

            String id = el.getAttribute(tagId);
            el.setIdAttribute("Id", true);

            XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", new XMLDSigRI());

            List<Transform> transformList = new ArrayList<Transform>();
            transformList.add(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null));
            transformList.add(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
                    (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null));

            Reference ref = fac.newReference("#" + id, fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
                    transformList, null, null);

            SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(
                    fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                    fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null),
                    Collections.singletonList(ref));

            KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
            X509Data x509Data = kif.newX509Data(Collections.singletonList(certificadoBean.getCertificado()));
            KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(x509Data));

            DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(certificadoBean.getChavePrivada(), el.getParentNode());

            XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
            signature.sign(dsc);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (MarshalException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (XMLSignatureException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Erro ao assinar o documento, verificar se o certificado " + "esta configurado corretamente");
    }

    return XMLW3CUtil.documentToString(doc);
}
```

porem apos isso chamo um método que faz a validação e é retornado que a assinatura não é válida, log mostrado durante processo de assinatura do xml e de validação da assinatura:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.LOGTXT
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "LOGTXT".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger         (com.consisa.global.utils.conexao.seguranca.CredentialManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
DEBUG Init:114 - Registering default algorithms
DEBUG DOMReference:312 - Marshalling Reference
DEBUG DOMReference:337 - Adding digestValueElem
DEBUG ResourceResolver:94 - check resolvability by class org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver
DEBUG ResolverFragment:131 - State I can resolve reference: "#ID1000608240001572017071915400600001"
DEBUG ResolverFragment:95 - Try to catch an Element with ID ID1000608240001572017071915400600001 and Element was [evtInfoEmpregador: null]
DEBUG DOMReference:423 - URIDereferencer class name: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer
DEBUG DOMReference:424 - Data class name: org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.ApacheNodeSetData
DEBUG Transform:360 - Create URI "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" class "class org.apache.xml.security.transforms.implementations.TransformEnvelopedSignature"
DEBUG Transform:362 - The NodeList is [Transform: null]
DEBUG ElementProxy:181 - setElement(Transform, "null"
DEBUG ApacheTransform:145 - Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature
DEBUG ApacheTransform:166 - ApacheData = true
DEBUG Transform:360 - Create URI "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" class "class org.apache.xml.security.transforms.implementations.TransformC14N"
DEBUG Transform:362 - The NodeList is [Transform: null]
DEBUG ElementProxy:181 - setElement(Transform, "null"
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:219 - Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:230 - ApacheData = true
DEBUG DigesterOutputStream:88 - Pre-digested input:
DEBUG DigesterOutputStream:93 - <evtInfoEmpregador xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_02_02" Id="ID1000608240001572017071915400600001"><ideEvento><tpAmb>3</tpAmb><procEmi>1</procEmi><verProc>11.27.062.05</verProc></ideEvento><ideEmpregador><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>00060824</nrInsc></ideEmpregador><infoEmpregador><inclusao><idePeriodo><iniValid>2010-01</iniValid></idePeriodo><infoCadastro><nmRazao>CONSISANET SISTEMAS DE INFORMACAO LTDA - EPP</nmRazao><classTrib>02</classTrib><natJurid>2313</natJurid><indCoop>0</indCoop><indConstr>0</indConstr><indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha><indOptRegEletron>1</indOptRegEletron><multTabRubricas>N</multTabRubricas><indEntEd>S</indEntEd><indEtt>N</indEtt><contato><nmCtt>SOCIO TESTE</nmCtt><cpfCtt>03202055925</cpfCtt><foneFixo>04699786912</foneFixo></contato><softwareHouse><cnpjSoftHouse>00060824000157</cnpjSoftHouse><nmRazao>CONSISA INFORMￃﾁTICA LTDA</nmRazao><nmCont>MARCIO RODRIGO DE BORTOLI</nmCont><telefone>04635201300</telefone></softwareHouse><infoComplementares><situacaoPJ><indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ></situacaoPJ></infoComplementares></infoCadastro></inclusao></infoEmpregador></evtInfoEmpregador>
DEBUG DOMReference:361 - Reference object uri = #ID1000608240001572017071915400600001
DEBUG DOMReference:373 - Reference digesting completed
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:269 - Signature provider:SunRsaSign version 1.8
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:270 - Signing with key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@fff8a957
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:271 - JCA Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
DEBUG Transform:360 - Create URI "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" class "class org.apache.xml.security.transforms.implementations.TransformC14N"
DEBUG Transform:362 - The NodeList is [CanonicalizationMethod: null]
DEBUG ElementProxy:181 - setElement(CanonicalizationMethod, "null"
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:219 - Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:235 - isNodeSet() = true
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:243 - Canonicalized SignedInfo:
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:248 - <SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#ID1000608240001572017071915400600001"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>Sm0qPUX+89hnOGkQP7hsxTNUIfAryCdYBWYXM1+OmJs=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:249 - Data to be signed/verified: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
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:222 - Signature provider:SunRsaSign version 1.8
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:223 - Verifying with key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 18850565723518694304036681294904955376724231871364234526408990712505004320383621186417985414445105832462854179885482777052872657757253057498276138689217124788313055652738068786152007030341157717350629030807302506296786052005145921775458384455332804013031584688081901027146715120332778706117692138572155315212459970637104450132114335517756099838544318343025698054701160186011605999191313387389709562683755957006454728356593750500899887605586015518285164570248753404551631162415424346573421063111556516263872766146218478987848418776173293386026256616764023342134329374433270339343343588810070112038383709045990970021627
  public exponent: 65537
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:224 - JCA Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:225 - Signature Bytes length: 256
DEBUG Transform:360 - Create URI "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" class "class org.apache.xml.security.transforms.implementations.TransformC14N"
DEBUG Transform:362 - The NodeList is [CanonicalizationMethod: null]
DEBUG ElementProxy:181 - setElement(CanonicalizationMethod, "null"
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:219 - Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:235 - isNodeSet() = true
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:243 - Canonicalized SignedInfo:
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:248 - <SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#ID1000608240001572017071915400600001"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>Sm0qPUX+89hnOGkQP7hsxTNUIfAryCdYBWYXM1+OmJs=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:249 - Data to be signed/verified: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
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:222 - Signature provider:SunRsaSign version 1.8
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:223 - Verifying with key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 18850565723518694304036681294904955376724231871364234526408990712505004320383621186417985414445105832462854179885482777052872657757253057498276138689217124788313055652738068786152007030341157717350629030807302506296786052005145921775458384455332804013031584688081901027146715120332778706117692138572155315212459970637104450132114335517756099838544318343025698054701160186011605999191313387389709562683755957006454728356593750500899887605586015518285164570248753404551631162415424346573421063111556516263872766146218478987848418776173293386026256616764023342134329374433270339343343588810070112038383709045990970021627
  public exponent: 65537
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:224 - JCA Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
DEBUG DOMSignatureMethod:225 - Signature Bytes length: 256
DEBUG Transform:360 - Create URI "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" class "class org.apache.xml.security.transforms.implementations.TransformC14N"
DEBUG Transform:362 - The NodeList is [CanonicalizationMethod: null]
DEBUG ElementProxy:181 - setElement(CanonicalizationMethod, "null"
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:219 - Created transform for algorithm: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315
DEBUG ApacheCanonicalizer:235 - isNodeSet() = true
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:243 - Canonicalized SignedInfo:
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:248 - <SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#ID1000608240001572017071915400600001"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>Sm0qPUX+89hnOGkQP7hsxTNUIfAryCdYBWYXM1+OmJs=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
DEBUG DOMSignedInfo:249 - Data to be signed/verified:PFNpZ25lZEluZm8geG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvMDkveG1sZHNpZyMiIHhtbG5zOnNvYXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3NvYXAvZW52ZWxvcGUvIj48Q2Fub25pY2FsaXphdGlvbk1ldGhvZCBBbGdvcml0aG09Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSLzIwMDEvUkVDLXhtbC1jMTRuLTIwMDEwMzE1Ij48L0Nhbm9uaWNhbGl6YXRpb25NZXRob2Q+PFNpZ25hdHVyZU1ldGhvZCBBbGdvcml0aG09Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDEvMDQveG1sZHNpZy1tb3JlI3JzYS1zaGEyNTYiPjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlTWV0aG9kPjxSZWZlcmVuY2UgVVJJPSIjSUQxMDAwNjA4MjQwMDAxNTcyMDE3MDcxOTE1NDAwNjAwMDAxIj48VHJhbnNmb3Jtcz48VHJhbnNmb3JtIEFsZ29yaXRobT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnI2VudmVsb3BlZC1zaWduYXR1cmUiPjwvVHJhbnNmb3JtPjxUcmFuc2Zvcm0gQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9UUi8yMDAxL1JFQy14bWwtYzE0bi0yMDAxMDMxNSI+PC9UcmFuc2Zvcm0+PC9UcmFuc2Zvcm1zPjxEaWdlc3RNZXRob2QgQWxnb3JpdGhtPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGVuYyNzaGEyNTYiPjwvRGlnZXN0TWV0aG9kPjxEaWdlc3RWYWx1ZT5TbTBxUFVYKzg5aG5PR2tRUDdoc3hUTlVJZkFyeUNkWUJXWVhNMStPbUpzPTwvRGlnZXN0VmFsdWU+PC9SZWZlcmVuY2U+PC9TaWduZWRJbmZvPg==
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: Mensagem XML com Assinatura Digital inválida
at com.consisa.esocial.teste.TesteEnvio.validarAssinatura(TesteEnvio.java:581)
at com.consisa.esocial.teste.TesteEnvio.validarAssinatura(TesteEnvio.java:448)
at com.consisa.esocial.teste.TesteEnvio.main(TesteEnvio.java:125)
```

Alguem pode me ajudar com essa assinatura digital ?

Comment: Estamos com o mesmo problema, ao enviar para o eSocial obtemos um erro de que o arquivo pode ter sido alterado após assinado ou que o certificado não é válido.
Nosso certificado parece ser válido pois não está revogado e conseguimos logar no e-CAC com ele. 
Enfim, apesar de a cadeia de certificados não se o problema, vc tem a cadeia de certificados instalada? https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain

Comment: Tente remover os atributos xmlns:xsd e xmlns:xsi do elemento eSocial.

Comment: é o mesmo problema que eu tive, para resolver assinei o xml apenas do evento, evtInfoEmpregador, peguei o xml desse evento junto com a tag parent dele o eSocial, e a assinatura passou a ser validada com sucesso pelo serviço, espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Cristian, pelo seu comentário me parece que você já resolveu o problema específico da sua questão original, mas, só lembrando que, para criar um lote válido para o eSocial:

- O XML do evento todo deve ser usado para criar a assinatura, nesse caso, desde a tag <eSocial> que precede a tag <evtInfoEmpregador> até a tag </eSocial> que fecha o evento (não a que fecha o lote), mas parece que foi justamente isso que você fez para resolver o problema.
- Como o Andre Rezende disse no comentário, os atributos xmlns:xsd e xmlns:xsi do elemento eSocial devem ser removidos, mas isso você já fez.
- O atributo URI do elemento Reference, da assinatura, deve estar vazio.
- Se o nrInsc informado no grupo ideEmpregador do evento for o CNPJ raiz com 8 dígitos (maioria dos casos), o nrInsc no grupo ideEmpregador do lote também deve ter apenas 8 dígitos, e o CNPJ usado para compor o Id do evento também deve ser o CNPJ de 8 dígitos, com zeros à direita para completar os 14 dígitos.

Eu criei duas páginas com algumas dicas sobre o eSocial, uma com dicas sobre a assinatura e outra com dicas de acesso ao serviço, vou deixar os links aqui porque pode ajudar outros:

- http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/AssinaturaXml.htm
- http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/AcessandoServicos.htm